# mysql memory grows too fast

Tags: mysql, memory

When mysql is started, the performance_shcema instrument is turned on. From the table memory_summary_global_by_event_name, the total used memory is 11G, but the physical memory used from ps and top is 24G. Where is the difference of 13G used in mysql? Is there any way to find out? thank you all

Comment: Check mysql configs. You may have set reserved memory of 24G for mysql. MySql is using 11G out of it. Other 13 is free but reserved for MySql

Comment: I didn't make it clear. innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 8G, and 24G is slowly rising.

Comment: Show us the output from `top` and your my.cnf.